Delphi Indy connection through Proxy using NTLM gives a POST exception
I am trying to connect to a web server through an NTLM proxy using Delphi 11.3 and the supplied Indy library.
I can make this work for GET commands, but for POST I get an EAbort exception.
If I access the server without using the proxy, it all works.
Simple program that demonstrates this below. There are options to select GET/POST and use proxy or not:
procedure TForm1.cbDoItClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  theResult: string;
  idHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  oStrings: TStringList;
begin

  oStrings := TStringList.Create;
  idHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    oStrings.Values['request'] := 'Hello';
    idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

    idHTTP1.ReadTimeout := 3000;
    idHTTP1.ConnectTimeout := 500;
    idHTTP1.IOHandler := idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];

    meResult.Lines.Add('*************************************************');
    meResult.Lines.Add('Start At ' + TimeToStr(now));

    if cbProxy.Checked then
    begin
      idHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := strtoint(edPort.Text);
      idHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := edProxy.Text;
      idHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyUsername := edProxyUser.Text;
      idHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := edProxyPass.Text;
      idHTTP1.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := false;
      idHTTP1.ProxyParams.Authentication := TIdSSPINTLMAuthentication.Create;
      idHTTP1.HTTPOptions := [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoInProcessAuth];

      meResult.Lines.Add('Proxy Port: ' + IntToStr(idHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort));
      meResult.Lines.Add('Proxy Host: ' + idHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer);
    end;

    try
      case rgVerb.ItemIndex of
        0:
          theResult := idHTTP1.Get(edGetURL.Text);
        1:
          theResult := idHTTP1.Post(edGetURL.Text, oStrings);
      end;

    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        meResult.Lines.Add('Exception Response = ' + idHTTP1.ResponseCode.ToString);
        meResult.Lines.Add(e.ClassName + ': ' + e.ToString);
      end;
    end;
    meResult.Lines.Add('');

    for var header in idHTTP1.Response.RawHeaders do
      meResult.Lines.Add('Header: ' + header);

    meResult.Lines.Add(theResult);
    meResult.Lines.Add('Response code: ' + IntToStr(idHTTP1.ResponseCode));

  finally
    idHTTP1.Free;
    oStrings.Free;
  end;

end;

The proxy server I am using for testing is WinGate. I am happy this is configured correctly as I can use CURL to access the same servers for both GET and POST.
Update 1
Call stack is 
The exception is raised in unit IdAuthenticationSSPI, TIdSSPINTLMAuthentication.Authentication, line 1250, step 2:
        if Length(FNTLMInfo) = 0 then begin
          Reset;
          Abort;  <- This line
        end;

I have added a breakpoint at the start of the Step 2 code. It is called twice for a POST - the first time, FNTLM is set to "NTLM " followed by what looks like a challenge string. The second time, it is set to "NTLM" only - no challenge. Calling "Fetch(FNTLMInfo);" sets FNTLM to blank.
The breakpoint only triggers once for GET
Update 2:
I have added some indy logging and have found that there is a difference in the response to the initial message sent to the proxy. For a GET, the Wingate server responds with
Connection: Keep-Alive
in the message. For a POST, the server responds with
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
This is the only difference I see. The Indy components then disconnect and send the NTLM challenge response first message whereas for GET, the connection remains and Indy sends the header:
Proxy-Authorization: NTLM [some characters]
Could this be the issue, and is there a way for Indy to handle the different keep-alive message? Reading the NTLM interface, the POST looks correct (apart from the last challenge which is ignored or is deemed incorrect by the proxy), but it is the GET that works.
GET with Auth
GET without Auth
POST without Auth
POST with Auth

Indy doesn't really treat a POST differently than GET, so I can't think of why one would work and the other doesn't. Also, AFAIK Indy doesn't ever raise EAbort (I'll have to check that). So, what does the call stack actually look like when EAbort is raised?

The call stack is as follows:

Hard to diagnose your problem without seeing the actual HTTP requests and responses. But in any case, do you have the same problem if you use TIdNTLMAuthentication instead of TIdSSPINTLMAuthentication?

Added Update 2. I will try and get the log files hosted and linked this afternoon

I found the answer to this.
Performing a POST message sets the HTTP Protocol to 1.0 which closes connections between each NTLM challenge/Response. This causes WinGate proxy to reset and not keep track of which message it is up to in the negotiation.
Adding hoKeepOrigProtocol to HTTPOptions makes this work.
